# Numerical Solutions in Maxima

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maxima

I have an equation in maxima and I want to find a numerical solution to the variable in this equation. I was wondering if anyone knew a what function in maxima operates most similar to that of FindRoot in mathematica?

There seems to be a couple of ways to do it but I am hoping to check results against that of a mathematica code, hence why I am interested in something similar to FindRoot.

Ben

Comment: Not sure about `FindRoot` but you can use the `numer` function to get the numerical result, e.g.: `1/3, numer` gives `0.33333333333333`.

Comment: Find numer is useful but I am not sure i can get it to help me in this situation. I need to solve for y in this equation.

    Ucr(y)-(offset+eigenvaluesort[6][[i]])=0;

with

    Ucr(y):=offset+c1[21]+2*sum(realpart(c1[m+20])
    *cos(2*3.14*(m-1)*y/dp) - imagpart(c1[m+20])*sin(2*3.14*
    (m-1)*y/dp),m,2,nmax+1);
    
I need to solve for y.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica's FindRoot searches for a numerical solution. The closest thing in Maxima (AFAIK) is find-root, which finds a numerical solution in a given interval.

Example:

```
(%i4) find_root(x^2=7,x,0,100);
(%o4)                          2.645751311064591
```